# Why did Umbrella never use Nemesis to kill zombies?

Tags: resident-evil, resident-evil-apocalypse

Why did Umbrella have never used Nemesis to kill every single zombie in Raccoon City? As much as I know, he was tested once, to kill all S.T.A.R.S. members, to test his "skills". But, never seen to kill any zombies. It is impossible that, umbrella was afraid, that he will be bit by a zombie, because:

1. He was bitten already in first movie, when he was still alive
2. He is somewhat of a Robot, (I guess, he can't feel pain)
3. He has a bloody Gatling Machine-gun and rocket launcher.

P.S: Also, just wanted to know, where did he disappear after 2nd movie of Resident Evil?

Comment: This would be the same Nemesis who got nuked in Racoon City?

Comment: Well, I belive yes, but did he really die? I haven't seen any questions about that in other movies, that I have seen. But still...
Wouldn't it be a better solution to kill zombies instead of bombing city?

Comment: Ah, well the question of why they fired a nuke is a good second question. The answer to your main question is yes, he couldn't be any more dead. He is literally the most dead that anything can possibly be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without wanting to point out the obvious, Nemesis (Addison) would be relatively useless as a zombie fighter, largely because he was vaporized when Raccoon City was nuked. He was close enough to ground zero that it's likely that his atoms became sort of smooth plasma roughly the temperature of the surface of the sun.

This was confirmed in the film's [official novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743493494), co-authored by the film's writer, Paul S. Anderson.

> It drove Isaacs crazy. Nemesis had been floundering for ages, and now they’d finally had a breakthrough. Abernathy and Addison were the perfect test subjects—Addison took to the mutations like a duck to water, and Abernathy had even taken it one step further.
>
> Did Cain let Isaacs do his job and refine the process?
>
> No, he’d let them loose in the city and set up some kind of idiotic death-cage match.
>
> **Now both subjects were as dead as Cain,** and Isaacs would need to start over.

and you can see the relevant scene here. Note that the blast is **directly above** Nemesis' last known location, pinned under the crashed helicopter:

Answer (score 4):

In Resident Evil: Apocalypse, He didn't kill any Zombies because it was never ordered to be. Nemesis was in fully control of Umbrella and was sent to kill surviving members of S.T.A.R.S. . But after fighting Alice he got back flashes of his memory and helped the survivor but he was killed by helicopter and then the whole city was caught under nuclear attack and there was no chance for Nemesis to survive.

Umbrella never ordered Nemesis to kill Zombies because they had something else in mind, Umbrella want to hide all his secret from government. If Nemesis killed the Zombies, there there will be proof all over the Raccoon city, so they preferred nuclear bombing more then Nemesis to clean whole the mess.

Answer (score -2):

Crushed by copter and then nuked they wanted him to kill stars as a test of how he good he would be against the top soldiers or terrorists in a war so they would win